# How do I fix this error message with Gazebo/Ogre plugin?

Tags: gazebo, linux, ubuntu, plugin, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I fix this error message?

---

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [RenderEngine.cc:356] Unable to load Ogre Plugin[/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so]...Skipping.

---

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32346/how-do-i-fix-this-error-message-with-gazebo/ogre-plugin?/) by [shyamalschandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2087/shyamalschandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I am facing the same problem as described above:

---

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Error [RenderEngine.cc:356] Unable to load Ogre Plugin[/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager.so]...Skipping.

---

I have already tried adding the ppa to ogre to source.list, and using apt-get manually reinstalling libogre and libogre-dev

This did not work, I am now stuck :/
I see this problem with 32bit and 64 bit installs of ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04
For all cases I have tried with the default nVidia driver installed.
I have than updated to the newest nVidia driver, then faced another problem as glxinfo showed that 3d support was unavailable.
the gazebo error then contained some major and minor fails when attempting to use glx.

according to NVidia, openGL support may require a restart after installing the new drivers, after having restarted, I end up with the same error as already shown.

glxgears runs as expected.

To test ogre is running I installed Tile Racer 0.7, which is based on ogre, and runs successfully.

The I moved my attention to the path the error mentions, and discovered that "Plugin_CgProgramManager.so" is not found in the OGRE lib. Apparently that is a known bug:
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=63267
it is not in the ubuntu package libogre.
this is because OGRE needs Nvidia Cg Toolkit to build CgProgramManager plugin.

> sudo apt-get install cmake

Then Following:
[building ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Building+Ogre)

especially the part about dependencies will install nVidia libraries like the Cg toolkit. Will take you through the ogre build process.

After this process the file exists, but is located in /usr/local/lib/OGRE

I reinstalled gazebo after this, as I had tried a lot of other stuff that broke it.
but it should be enough to reconfigure gazebo to look for ogre at the new installation location, or create a symlink or...

---

Originally posted by [zcuba](https://answers.ros.org/users/2757/zcuba/) with karma: 31 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0